# Passing two-dimentional array to Web API server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web, asp.net-web-api

I would like to make a Web Api server request that looks like this :

```
localhost:8080/GetByCoordinates/[[100,90],[180,90],[180,50],[100,50]]
```

As you can see, there is an array of coordinates. each coordinate has two points, and i would like to make a request like this.
I cannot figure out how my Web Api Route Config should look like, and how the method signature should be.

Can you help out ? thanks !

Comment: Your URI is not valid, you need to pass as query string or in body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way might be to use a 'catch-all' route and parse it in the controller action. For example

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetByCoordinatesRoute",
            routeTemplate: "/GetByCoordinatesRoute/{*coords}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "GetByCoordinatesRoute" }

public ActionResult GetByCoordinatesRoute(string coords)
{
    int[][] coordArray = RegEx.Matches("\[(\d+),(\d+)\]")
                              .Cast<Match>()
                              .Select(m => new int[] 
                                      {
                                          Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value),
                                          Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[2].Value)
                                      })
                              .ToArray();
}
```

*Note*: my parsing code is supplied just as an example. It's a lot more forgiving that what you asked for, and you probably need to add a more checks to it.

However, a more elegant solution would be to use a custom [`IModelBinder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505004%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

```
public class CoordinateModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        int[][] result;
        // similar parsing code as above
        return result;
    }
}

public ActionResult GetByCoordinatesRoute([ModelBinder(typeof(CoordinateModelBinder))]int[][] coords)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious question is why do you want that info to be in the URL? It looks like something that is better dealt with as JSON.

So you could do `localhost:8080/GetByCoordinates/?jsonPayload={"coords": [[100,90],[180,90],[180,50],[100,50]]}`